# Detect when a file is created (on a webserver) and ready for use in one of many directories

Tags: c#, websites, file-systems

I have an odd, intermittent bug that is happening on a web server.

One of the methods triggers the creation of a small file (3kb), in a folder. The folder is based on the current year, month and location id.

The file is created by a 3rd party component that I have no control over, other than by calling its `CreateImage()` method.

The developers of this component have confirmed that they hand the creation of the file over to the OS and then return without checking if the creation happened. (Nice).

What we then try to do is to open this file, and write a specific authorisation code on it. However, occasionally the log files are catching a `System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid` when I call  `Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(filename);` According to MSDN this exception means that the file is not an image file, or is not actually there.

I can't affect the 3rd party component, But I am pretty sure that Running a `FileSystemWatcher` on a website process is not going to cut it either, nor is any kind of blocking call where I wait for an unknown amount of time for the file to be created. The only other solution I can think of off the top of my head is to check if the file is there, if not, check after a second, and then a third time. If after all that it is not present, to throw an exception. But that just feels more like a 'bodge' than a fix.

I can't put these image creations and alterations into some kind of queue or other process, as the updated image is displayed back to the user on the next page.

Have I missed any obvious solutions to my problem here, before I need to go back and try to re-invent the whole process (Which seems overkill for maybe 1 in 500) images causing a problem?

Comment: "Open-ended" isn't the criteria for posting here.    See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: As to your problem, you would fix it the same way you fix any other problem of this kind: wrap it in a retry mechanism if it fails?

Comment: I accept that is probably where I will have to go with this, but like I have said above, it feels more like a bodge than a fix. However, not every problem need have an elegant solution I guess!

Comment: It's not elegant, but it has the distinction of not requiring you to re-invent the whole process.

Comment: Do you know for a fact the the exceptions are in fact caught by proper image files and not what looks like being image files ?

Comment: Good question @frostings. I cannot be100% sure, this only happens sporadically on a production server, so I am going to implement a retry system, and if that fails, I will need to quarantine the affected file so we can investigate further.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a system of different components which you don't have under your control, at a certain level of complexity some of the components will fail sometimes. That is especially true when your system involves several machines, hardware and networks, but can sometime also happen on just one machine.

The only sensible approach for this I know is to make your software more robust and [fault-tolerant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_computer_system). Retry mechanisms are a standard way to do this (as well as redundancy), they are not a "bodge", as you called it. [Here is an example (Apache Flink)](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/batch/fault_tolerance.html) for another system which creates robustness using a retry mechanics. Maybe it you can solve your problem in a similar manner.

Comment: Absolutely agree.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title:

> Detect when a file is created (on a webserver) ?

It is obviously [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) and [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific.

However, most web servers are running some variant of Linux today. Then, if the file system is local (not a remote one like NFS or CIFS) and proper to Linux (e.g. ext4, BTRFS, XFS, ... but not VFAT or NTFS) then you could consider [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities to detect file creation.

You might use the [inotifywait(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html) & [inotifywatch(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywatch.1.html) commands or the [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) daemon (or code your own program above *inotify* related system calls).

Comment: Apologies, I missed that out. It is a Windows server.